# GeckoView-based Kiosk app?

Tags: firefox-for-android, kiosk-mode

I've had trouble with video playback using Android Kiosk. I gather it's because of the apps reliance on WebView. Firefox is playing the videos well.

Is there a current Kiosk app available based on GeckoView? Or is there an effective way of putting Firefox in kiosk mode?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.mozilla.org/wo/questions/925765) post briefly mentions [SureFox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surefox&hl=en_US&gl=US) that looks to have recent updates, although other than the name, it's not immediately clear it's based on Firefox, so you might need to test if it works correctly for your application.

[AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/quick-guides/android-firefox-kiosk-mode/) seems like a good option, although it may require a subscription to use.

Depending on your device and application, you could also explore [pinning apps](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?hl=en) - it's an Android feature that should be included in almost all recent versions and can be accomplished without any additional software. The downside is that, while simple, it's more geared toward preventing temporary user access, and can be undone rather easily by someone familiar with the feature, although they'd be met with a passcode if you've set one. Here are the steps for this feature:

#### Turn on app pinning

- Open your phone's Settings app.
- Tap Security or Security & location and then Advanced and then App pinning.

  - If you can't find it, get help from your device manufacturer.
- Turn on App pinning.
- When app pinning is on, you need to enter your PIN, pattern, or password before you can unpin.

#### Pin a screen

##### After turning on app pinning:

- Go to the screen you want to pin.
- Swipe up to the middle of your screen and hold or use 3-button navigation: Tap Overview
- At the top of the image, tap the app's icon.
- Tap Pin.

#### Unpin a screen

- Gesture navigation: Swipe up and hold.
- 2-button navigation: Touch and hold Back  and Home .
- 3-button navigation: Touch and hold Back  and Overview .
- If you're asked for your PIN, pattern, or password, enter it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into these tips tomorrow

Comment: Let us know how they go!

Comment: I haven't had a chance yet to test Airdroid. Hopefully today. I did test SureFox and it seems to behave in the same way as Android Kiosk. ie. the video crashes. So I think it is "fox" in name only. Will report back!

Comment: I've been testing Airdroid. It's excellent and works without crashing-out my videos. For this I've been using the "Kiosk Browser" app that comes with Airdroid. It requires "device owner permission" of the Android device to be set. Great remote management of devices. The problem however is going to be price as from what I know you have to subscribe a minimum of 10 devices. With the exchange rate here, that's expensive. I'll try pinning again sometime soon - couldn't get it to work earlier. I worry though that it won't offer much in the way of full-screen capacity.

Comment: In my application, an exhibition, I don't really have to lock-down the device as it's not directly manipulated by the public. What I need mostly is full screen, with automatic set up when the device is turned on. Firefox plays my pages very well, but requires touching the screen to set it up with full screen (with the addition of a secondary app), and this is going to be inconvenient.